# Flutter App Crashes when press on pay now button

Tags: java, android, flutter, stripe-payments

I am integrating payment methods in my flutter app and when the user press the pay now button the app crashes and throws the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field type of type Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/stripe/android/model/PaymentMethod; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethod' appears in /data/app/~~VO5aj2yr8kwr96XX9YId_A==/com.apppackage.name-8pPD2CBi6ztF0vTAUvqM3w==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
```

with the **PID: 5692 SIG: 9**.

I am using the stripe_payment package and it has almost no documentation.

Comment: This should be reported to Stripe, seems to be an issue coming from that sdk.

Comment: I have open an issue at the stripe_payment package too, but still, there is no response there.

Comment: It is a discontinued package. It references to https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe

Comment: I have tried that package too but it does not work for me as there is no documentation for that package too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**
In my case, it was my **pubspec.lock** file which was generating the error, because I have tried multiple dependencies related to stripe so I think it was overriding them and when I run that particular piece of code it through's that error and app get crashed.
So, I just delete that file and then get the packages again by using

```
flutter pub get
```

And then run the project again and it works fine.